# CodeIgniter (Perfex CRM) not generating consecutive IDs for entries, how to fix that?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Perfex CRM which is developed by using CodeIgniter framework. I'm having an issue that the IDs of the are records not consecutive even after I delete the older records. Like the below image.

Any idea what topic I should be looking for to fix this issue?

[ID Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylob0.png)

Comment: The Id's are normally Auto Incremented. So your image shows that you must have deleted id's 2 to 9. They do not get re-used when you delete an entry.

Comment: So there's no way to disable this auto increment?

Comment: Have you checked that the id is auto incremented? Why do they need to be consecutive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the prefex crm table you can fins a respective files folder
**application > views > admin > tables**

For The perfex custom modules it depends on the developer who developed it. Hope this helps you let me know if further help needed

```
$sr = 0;
foreach ($rResult as $aRow) {
    $row[] = $sr++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the developer is calling the fetch data real ids in the database

so try doing this on the looping of the project summary code add this

```php
$id = 1;

foreach ($psummaries as $summa) // this depend on what the developer is using for looping
    ?>
    echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $i++ . '</td> // use this to replace $summa->id or $summa['id'] depending if the data is object or array
        <td>....</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry about this noob question, where can I find this? in the model, controller, or view?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply  @MohamedShamoon You will see this within the view file